# Error reading from Excel in C#: "...could not find the object..."

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I have more or less exactly the same error as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496137/problems-reading-a-xlsx-file), but that solution has not solved my problem.

The error message I get:

```
The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object 'Adresser$'.  
Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.
```

I have checked and double-checked that the name is right, I have renamed the sheet and copy-pasted the name into my code, but nothing seems to work. What am i doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
string conStr = String.Format(
    @"Provider={0};Data Source=""{1}"";Extended Properties=""{2}""",
                "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0",
                "REGISTER 090310.xls",
                "Excel 12.0 Xml;IMEX=1;HDR=YES;");
DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb");
using (IDbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
{
    connection.ConnectionString = conStr;
    using (IDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [Adresser$]";
        connection.Open();

        // The exception is thrown on this line, with yellow highlight on
        // IDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader()
        using (IDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(  
                    string.Format("First name: {0}\tLast name: {1}", 
                        dr[0].ToString(), 
                        dr[1].ToString()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any chance it should be Addresser$?  Two d's?

Comment: Nope - in Swedish it's spelled with only one d... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I solved it:

It turns out, this provider was able to connect correctly to an Excel 2003 worksheet, but couldn't read it. Thus, I **opened the worksheet in Excel 2007 and re-saved it in the `.xlsx` format**, and changed my connection string accordingly. It all works now =)

Comment: That's sick (I mean that as a bad thing, whatever the current slang). It should _always_ be able to read older versions unless there's a WELL publicized break.

Comment: It is sick. The worst thing is that it complained about not finding the worksheet - not about not being able to read the file. Not only is the problem silly, the error message isn't directly helpful either... Sigh...

Comment: I had forgotten to specify the extension of the file, so it could not find it - but the error was that it could not find the worksheet!