# query for reading data from excel sheet in c#

Tags: excel, c#-4.0

*Thanks **Astander** for replying to my query*

I am here with more detailed query.

```
        string cs = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=" + @"D:\\sample.xls;" + "Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;";
        OleDbConnection Excelcon = new OleDbConnection(cs);
        OleDbDataAdapter ad = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        ad.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT *FROM [Sheet1$]", Excelcon);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        ad.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
```

I am getting error at the select statement that :

> **The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1$'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.**

Hope someone can help me find a solution.

Comment: Can you please show us the *actual code*?

Comment: Thanq Astander.I am now with a more detailed query.Hope u will go through it.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is,
when file was created, it was stored in some specific location. In my case,`C:/Documents`.

I had manually changed the location to D:
this was what I had written

> string connStringExcel = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;                                                                                                                                Data Source=***D:\example.xls***;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;""";`

So,the actual path should be

> string connStringExcel = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;                                                                                                                                Data Source=C:\A\Documents\example.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;""";`

So on giving the path of correct location,my query was solved.

Hope it helps someone else too.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create connection string variable. Modify the "Data Source"
// parameter as appropriate for your environment.
String sConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
"Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("../ExcelData.xls") + ";" +
"Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";

// Create connection object by using the preceding connection string.
OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(sConnectionString);

// Open connection with the database.
objConn.Open();

// The code to follow uses a SQL SELECT command to display the data from the worksheet.

// Create new OleDbCommand to return data from worksheet.
OleDbCommand objCmdSelect =new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM myRange1", objConn);

// Create new OleDbDataAdapter that is used to build a DataSet
// based on the preceding SQL SELECT statement.
OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter();

// Pass the Select command to the adapter.
objAdapter1.SelectCommand = objCmdSelect;

// Create new DataSet to hold information from the worksheet.
DataSet objDataset1 = new DataSet();

// Fill the DataSet with the information from the worksheet.
objAdapter1.Fill(objDataset1, "XLData");

// Bind data to DataGrid control.
DataGrid1.DataSource = objDataset1.Tables[0].DefaultView;
DataGrid1.DataBind();

// Clean up objects.
objConn.Close();
```

ref to [thisLink](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/306572/how-to-query-and-display-excel-data-by-using-asp-net-ado-net-and-visua)